# Allow comment upvoting from flag screen

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

Of late (based on the 10k tools' flags tab), I have seen a lot of people being just awesome to each other in the comments. Sometimes it is the same people who realize that some people are better off not having their hands held.

The way I see it one of the best places to find comments that I want to upvote is the comment flag screen, but the functionality for upvoting those comments isn't present there. I have to click another button first and that makes my brain tired.

I believe that by doing this we'll encourage better comments that will help people get over not thinking for themselves. We already have the ability to flag things in that list, which is counterproductive and backward. We should have the ability to upvote things from that list instead.

Comment: Also we should have an "exact opposite" close reason for questions that are parodied. Not for the parody question, but for the parodied question.